# How to serve static images from host system to the docker container?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I need help making Flask use images from a directory (path is passed via program arguments using `argparse`). The problem is, i need to make this work with Docker to use a host directory inside the container.

Check my directory structure:

```
Static/0.png
main.py
```

Flask Code: main.py

```
import argparse
import flask

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--path",default="static")
args = parser.parse_args()

app = Flask(__name__,static_folder=args.path)
app.route("/")

def init():
    path = os.path.join(args.path,"0.png")
    return "<img src="+path+"/>"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python","main.py"]
```

Observe that when I use the `Static/` directory inside the container, it works, but when I use a path outside the container, it does not work.

Comment: How do you run docker?

Comment: docker run -d --rm docker_name

Answer (score 1):

You could create a **VOLUME** to do that.

In your Dockerfile:

```
VOLUME /app/static_files
...
ENTRYPOINT ["python","main.py", "/app/static_files"]
```

And while running your container, you have to specify the path of the static files with the argument `-p <path>:/app/static_files`